# I want to install mysql8.0 on ubuntu18.10, but apt keeps trying to install mysql5.7, why?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apt, dpkg

Here are the steps of my installation:

1. sudo wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
2. sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
3. In the Configuration GUI, choose mysql 8.0, and enter OK to exit GUI
4. sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Then I got some messages:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/20.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 159 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

if I enter Y, apt will install mysql5.7, not the version of 8.0, just as the message said.
How can I install the expected version?

Comment: I think [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-debian.html) might help...

Comment: the doc indicates 2 methods to install mysql. I've tried the first one(The MySQL APT Repository) and failed, should i try the second:"The MySQL Developer Zone's Download Area"?

Comment: And i found this: [Installing MySQL on Linux Using the MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-apt-repo.html), it seems that ubuntu18.10 is not supported by mysql8.0?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by install an older version of mysql8:
[mysql-server_8.0.13](https://cdn.mysql.com/archives/mysql-8.0/mysql-server_8.0.13-1ubuntu18.10_amd64.deb-bundle.tar)

Here is the entry of download page: [Archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)